# Filtering parent <div> elements based on inner child elements [Python]

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a beautiful soup element result set that contains several  parents elements, each containing inner elements. How would I go about trying to filter these elements based on the text of eachs inner element.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div> ... <div>
    <p class="example"> TRUE </p>
</div>
```

In the example, say I want to only keep elements that have an inner p element which has a value of 'TRUE'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup allows you to give a [*function as filter*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).

You could give a [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) expression like

```
lambda elem:elem.find('p',text=re.compile('TRUE')
```

inside the [*find_all()*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all). If the child with the text is not available this will return a empty list. Since [*any empty sequence is considered false*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in python, this will filter out the unwanted elements.

```
html="""
<div class="parent">
    <p class="example"> TRUE </p>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <p class="example"> TRUE </p>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <p class="example">FALSE </p>
</div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Tag
import re
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all(lambda elem:elem.find('p',text=re.compile('TRUE'))))
```

Outputs:

```
[<div class="parent">
<p class="example"> TRUE </p>
</div>, <div class="parent">
<p class="example"> TRUE </p>
</div>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like xpath would work. Something like

```
//p[contains(@class, 'example') and normalize-space(text()) = 'TRUE']/ancestor::div[@class='parent']
```

Comment: So if for example I am originally storing all of the unfiltered parent elements in "results". What would this query look like on that variable?

Comment: I am also getting a syntax error pointing to "parent" at ancestor::div[@class='parent']

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do this using CSS selectors in BeautifulSoup 4.7+.

Here we will target every `div` which has a direct/immediate child `p` with class `example` that contains the text `TRUE`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Tag
html="""
<div class="parent">
    <p class="example"> TRUE </p>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <p class="example"> TRUE </p>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <p class="example">FALSE </p>
</div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select('div:has(> p.example:contains(TRUE))'))
```

Output

```
[<div class="parent">
<p class="example"> TRUE </p>
</div>, <div class="parent">
<p class="example"> TRUE </p>
</div>]
```